# Tamanho máximo, limite de conexões e qual versão do SQL Server devo usar em minha aplicação desktop

Tags: sql-server

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema e estou utilizando banco SQL Server 2014, porém o gratuito. Qual versão posso utilizar para que não fique limitando os recursos do meu banco quando chegar em um tamanho maior ou ultrapassar uma quantidade de conexões?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Limite todo banco de dados possui, o SQL Server com menos limitações é o Enterprise (caríssimo), e o Standard resolve bem a maioria dos casos. Claro que se precisa de recursos do Enterprise provavelmente já será um DBA bem experiente e esta informação é irrelevante.

Em alguns casos pode ser bom usar a edição Web ou até o Azure (assinatura em nuvem) e pagar pelo que usa efetivamente.

Quando precisa resolver dúvidas assim pode sempre consultar a página do produto que tem tudo.

Há uma [página com comparação entre as edições diferentes do SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-2017&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: A limitação máxima de conexões abertas no SQL Server ê de 32k. Se você estiver fazendo algo **_muito_** errado, chega nesse valor muito antes de ser realmente necessário fazer o _shard_. Experiência própria... Ah, não sei qual a versão usada no trabalho, mas não encontrei nada em fontes indicando um valor maior. Talvez em outras edições tenha um valor máximo menor, mas parece mesmo que esse 32k é um _hard limit_

Comment: Depois de 10k, afunda tanto que já acho impraticável em qq hw.

Answer (score 0):

Quando você está desenvolvendo uma solução (ou uma aplicação), você deve ter em conta alguns pontos:

1. Quantos utilizadores farão uso simultâneo da Base de Dados
2. Qual é o volume (em MB/GB) de informação que será hospedado ao fim de X tempo (de preferência ano(s))

Particularmente, acredito que estes pontos são críticos para saber quais edições e/ou versões do SQL Server são adequadas à sua solução.

Conselho: opte sempre por usar as últimas versões. Elas suportam tudo o que as anteriores suportam com o acréscimo de terem novas funcionalidades.

Para soluções mais simples em que a concorrência por dados é relativamente baixa (lojinhas, site com poucas visitas) o SQL Server Express responde muito bem. Ele vem com 10GB, consumo máximo de 1GB de RAM por BD e aceita até 5 conexões simultâneas com o seu servidor. É verdade que as aplicações de hoje em dia usam conexões em que abrem, realizam as querys necessárias e voltam a fechar a conexão, tudo muito rápido.

Cenários mais complexos que esses, eu recomendo SQL Server Standard.